# Graph API: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-functions, microsoft-graph-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I have the following permissions on my registered **Azure Function.**.
This azure function will work as web hook and called by some application/API

[image: App Permission]

but when I try to get data

```
public async Task<string> FindUpnByEmail(string email)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(email)) return email;

       try
        {
            var request = new RestRequest("users")
                .AddQueryParameter("$filter", $"mail eq '{email}'")
                .AddQueryParameter("$select", "userPrincipalName");
            var rest = new RestClient(GraphUrl)
            {
                Authenticator = await GetAuthenticator(),
            };
            var response = await rest.ExecuteGetAsync(request);
            var userResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ODataResponse<User>>(response.Content);
            return userResponse.Value.Length > 0 ? userResponse.Value[0].UserPrincipalName : email;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return email;
        }    
}
```

I receive the following error:

> Authorization_RequestDenied","message":"Insufficient privileges to
> complete the operation.

Comment: What does your `GetAuthenticator()`?

Answer (score -1):

Try to update the Admin consent to Yes for profile, Read Basic profile.

Or Add read write delegate permission and grant admin consent for that as well.

Comment: are you using the client secret key for authentication?